# Moving an id from cell to relative cell in a table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, attributes, cell

I want to "move" an id from one cell in a table to a relative cell in the table.

To simplify things, let's say I have this:

```
<tr><td></td><td id='a'></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

One of the cells has `id='a'` but I don't know which it will be. I simply want to make the one to the right of it have `id='a'`.

Getting the cell with `id='a'` and un-setting the id is simple enough:

```
var cell_a = $('#a');
cell_a.attr('id','');
```

However, I'm not sure how to get the cell to the right. I tried a few things with `cell_a.parent().children()` and `cell_a.parent().find()` but wasn't able to just pull out a list.  Once I get the one to the right it will obviously be something like:

```
var new_cell_a = ?
new_cell_a.attr('id','a');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `cell_a.next()`

like explained in this page: http://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: Okay, a related question; what if, instead of wanting to move right one cell, I want to move down one? I can get the proper row with `cell_a.parent().next()` but how do I get the cell?

Comment: That would be `cell_a.parent().next().children()[0]`. You can find the complete list of traversal commands here: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method like this:

```
$("#a").removeAttr('id').end().next().attr('id', 'a');
```

The `next()` method is used there to find the element next to what is specified in previous selector `$("#a")` and then `attr` is used to change its id.

Comment: `td[id='a']`? Why would you use such a complicated and slow selector as there is only one element with id `a`?

Comment: @Harmen: Updated before seeing your comment :)

Comment: If I set the id on the new element, will that unset it on the old one?

Comment: @kerkeslager:No you will have to remove that explicitily, updated for that :)